# Reinstall mysql in Xampp for Windows 10

Tags: mysql, xampp, recovery

I was trying to delete other file but mistakenly I did shift+del for my mysql folder under Xampp. Now my entire application running in localhost is not able to locate mysql. My bad!!

Is there any way out to recover that folder or reinstall just the mysql in Xampp. I tried Easeus and Yodot software for folder recovery but none of them proved no luck to detect my permanently deleted folder.

Please suggest me what can be the alternative way out. 
P.S. I am having my mysql config file backup saved.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic for SO. You may get help at the superuser site.

Comment: Follow this link read and understand the answers very well.
https://superuser.com/questions/566013/how-can-i-upgrade-the-mysql-version-included-in-xampp

Answer (score 3):

I think the simple and better way is reinstall the xampp e.g to folder xampp2 then move your script into the htdocs of the new install

Comment: Thanks. This method worked. But now, what I want is XAMPP runs MySQL with MariaDB server 10.1 . I want to use JSON functionality in v10.2. How should I update the MariaDB server version in XAMPP?